# XCTest - How to query for substring in navbar title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I would like to be able to verify that a substring appears in the navigation bar in a UI test.

For example, if the nav bar title is "Rent Properties" then I can match it like so:

```
XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Rent Properties"].exists)
```

However, this has two issues:

- If the text is not in a nav bar it will still match
- It does an exact match, whereas I want to be able to match a substring such as "Rent"

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For matching substring Rent, you can use the below code:

```
XCUIApplication().staticTexts.matchingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Rent'")).elementBoundByIndex(0)
//it may contains one or more element with substring Rent.
//you have to find out which element index you want in debug mode using p print() options.
```

For the first option, there certainly must be a difference while element is showing or not showing. you have to find out it using po or p print option in debug mode.

For example, there may the count is different or the element is not hittable or so on....

you may try to use :

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Rent Properties"].exists)

or 
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.staticTexts["Rent Properties"].hittable

or
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.staticTexts["Rent Properties"].enabled

or 

app.staticTexts.matchingIdentifier("Rent Properties").count
//take count while showing the text and take the count while not showing the text
```

Answer (score 5):

Try out these.

1.Get the static text from the element instead of getting from appication.

```
  Eg:`XCUIApplication().navigationBars["Rent Properties"].staticTexts["Rent Properties"]`
```

2. Use `elementMatchingPredicate` or `expectationForPredicate` to for matching the element.

Useful Link:http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/